# Laravel datatables , not able to get the data to the view in the datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

This is my Controller file

It works for external url but not when i pass data from controller to view

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;


class EventsController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){


        $events = DB::connection('pgsql')->select("select * from events where passcode='xxxxxxx' limit 100");

        return view('/tools/realtimedata',compact('events'));
    }
}
```

This is my datatable code

```
 $("#meetingform").submit(function(e) {
        $('#tablerecords').dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                    "url": "/events",
                    "dataSrc":""
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "time"},
                {"data": "class"},
                {"data": "passcode"},
            ],
});
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you can't do? when you use this return view('/tools/realtimedata',compact('events')); does not work? explain a little better please

Comment: The events data that I am returning is not getting displayed in the dataTable , even when I use {{$events->id }}

Comment: if you return $events; it does display data?

Comment: yes it does if its outside the dataTable but it doesnt display when i try to access it in dataTable

Comment: When you pass information to the datatables it expects json. When you are passing a view you want to render html, that's where it goes wrong. Just return json in your controller method and handle that with the datatables

Answer (score 0):

It may be the way you're fetching the data, check in the network tab on the console to see if the data is being fetched.

or maybe you're calling the ajax in the wrong way, the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) says that you just put the url like this

```
$("#meetingform").submit(function(e) {
        $('#tablerecords').dataTable({
            "ajax": "/events",//you have to check if the call is being made
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "time"},
                {"data": "class"},
                {"data": "passcode"},
            ],
});
```